# Unwrapping an Optional value which is nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am having a common error which involves optionals, and I have a `NSUserDefault` value which is the users location using the Location Manager Function:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{

    //First Convert it to NSNumber.
    let lat : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let lng : NSNumber = NSNumber(double: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    //Store it into Dictionary
    let locationDict = ["lat": lat, "lng": lng]

    //Store that Dictionary into NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationDict, forKey: "Location")
}
```

When I run my app, it crashes at on the line `let userLoc = NSUserDefaults`... on the following code block in my viewDidLoad() method.

```
    let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as! [String : NSNumber]

    //Grab location from that Dictionary (from func LocationManager below)
    let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
    let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

    //declare MKPointAnnotation()
    var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.latitude = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.longitude = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees
```

And the error is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
```

I suspect this is because I havent stored the variable

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location")
```

until AFTER the `viewDidLoad` method ran.

How do I avoid this error? 
Should I run the `locationManager()` function in my view did load?  
I tried that it there was an error...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  I have been stuck on this for a few hours.

Josh

Comment: Where would I call this?  In the viewDidLoad( ) or the locationManager( )?

Comment: right after you do `setObject:`

Comment: If you're new to Swift, try to avoid using `!` as much as you can. The majority of the time it's a bad/hacky decision when you use it.

Comment: @KelvinLau no need to force synchronize

Comment: @KelvinLau Forcing `synchronize` is completely unnecessary and besides wasting processor time, almost never actually accomplishes anything that wouldn't've been accomplished anyway at a more efficient time.

Comment: I disagree @AdamPro13. You should be using `!` as much as you can. It'll reduce your code length, thus improving readability. My condition for not using forced unwrapping is only when the situation is non - deterministic, and you'll only understand when you should use `!` and when you should use `?` through experience.

Comment: @LeoDabus You are correct, I apologize for not making it clear; I wanted him to synchronize only for the purposes of debugging the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful when you use '!' to unwrap an optional or cast a value.  This says *"I know that this is not nil/an instance of this class and if it isn't, this is bad and throw an exception"*.

If there is a possibility that it is nil/not an instance of the desired class, then you should use '?' and act on the result appropriately.

```
if let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as? [String : NSNumber] {

    //Grab location from that Dictionary (from func LocationManager below)
    let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
    let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

    //declare MKPointAnnotation()
    var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.latitude = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.longitude = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees
}
```

Your second use of '!' - when you assign the latitude/longitude to the coordinate is correct - If the cast doesn't succeed then there is something wrong with the data that you stored and crashing is probably a reasonable approach so that you can debug.

If the data was coming from some external source and could potentially be invalid the use of '?' and some sort of error handling could still be the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

How about wrap it with a `if` statement if you are not sure whether it's still `nil` at that point?

```
if let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Location") as? [String : NSNumber] {

    //Grab location from that Dictionary (from func LocationManager below)
    let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
    let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

    //declare MKPointAnnotation()
    var Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //Convert NSNumber to CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.latitude = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees
    Annotation.coordinate.longitude = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees
}
```

If you are certainly sure it shouldn't be `nil` at that point (viewDidLoad:), you might have to provide us more code so we can help you to determine where went wrong.

Remember, always make sure it's not `nil` before you unwrap it, if not, don't use `!`.

Answer (score -2):

You must check if you are using a `comma ","` instead of a `dot "."` in the string that you are trying to cast to Double.

This throw nil error :

```
let latitude : CLLocationDegrees = Double("9,123")!
```

This is the right way :

```
let latitude : CLLocationDegrees = Double("9.123")!
```